# Error when Uploading an RSDS File to SharePoint, collection and SSRS out of synch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have a site collection with an RSDS file in it that gets modified by a powershell script. The script downloads the rsds file, modifies it, then uploads the new copy. It works great but the file is never synched between SharePoint 2010 and SSRS. I did some digging and I found the error below in the ULS log. Has anyone seen this before?

``` Failed to sync DataSource 'https://server.com/sites/mysite/Data Connections for PerformancePoint/connection.rsds' to Report Server: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Client.ReportingWebServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnApplication[T](String operationName, String siteUrl, String xmlNamespace, Action``2 method) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Client.ReportingWebServiceApplicationProxy.Invoke[T](SPServiceContext serviceContext, String operationName, String siteUrl, String xmlNamespace, Guid serviceInstanceId, Action``2 method) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Client.ReportingWebServiceApplicationProxy.Invoke[T](SPServiceContext serviceContext, String operationName, String siteUrl, String xmlNamespace, Action``2 method) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Client.ReportingWebServiceApplicationProxy.Invoke[T](SPServiceContext serviceContext, String operationName, String siteUrl, String xmlNamespace, Action``1 method) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Client.ReportingWebServiceClient.Execute[TResult](String methodName, Func``2 action) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ReportingServiceAppConnection.Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsProxy.IRSConnection.GetProperties(String item, IList``1 property) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsProxy.SrvProxy.GetProperties(String item, IList``1 property) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ItemEventHandler.SyncItemToRS(SPItemEventProperties properties) ```

Edit 4/7/2017:
This is still a problem. I discovered yesterday that this also happens when PowerView (rdlx) report files are created.

To create report files the application uses [SPListItem CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.copyto(v=office.14).aspx) to create a copy of a blank RDLX file that already has the appropriate connection information.

From the ULS Log:

```
SQL Server Reporting Services SOAP Client Proxy 0000 High Failed to sync RdlxReport 
'https://server.com/sites/mysite/Reports/ReportFile1.rdlx' to Report Server: 
System.ServiceModel.FaultException``1[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.RsExceptionInfo]: 
The item 'https://server.com/sites/mysite/Reports/ReportFile1.rdlx' cannot be found. ---> 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: 
The item 'https://server.com/sites/mysite/Reports/ReportFile1.rdlx' cannot be found. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.RsExceptionInfo).
```

When I ran [Debug Diagnostics v2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) on the front-end server I captured this in the log:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException``1
[[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.RsExceptionInfo, 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract]] on thread 2452. DetailID = 8
  Thread created. New thread - System ID: 3576
```

When I enabled verbose logging I also found this in the ULS log:

```
WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://my-ssrs:32843/71db4e0d7ecd48bfa4c39b986d3d69b3/ReportingWebService.svc' Channel:
'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.IReportServiceManagement' Action: 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2011/06/01/ReportServer/Management/GetProperties' MessageId: 
'urn:uuid:700ac901-383b-4d25-9f22-8b7ef78196ec'
```

I opened that WCF service URL from each of the SharePoint servers and the page comes up.

Comment: What is the status of the SSRS Proxy and Service Instance? Is the Proxy tied to the specified Web Application Proxy Group?

Comment: I may need a little more information to answer that question.

Comment: Proxy Group info is under Application Management -> Configure service application associations. SA/Proxy status info is listed on Manage Service Applications. Lastly, the status of the Service Instance is on Manage services on server.

Comment: My Reporting Service Proxy is in the "default" Application Proxy Group which is the one for my Web Application. The Service Application and Proxy are Started, and the "SQL Server Reporting Services Service"  is Started

Comment: I've had problems in the past trying to copy and move .RSDS and .RDL files around in SharePoint through code rather than the UI - seems like Reporting Services does maintain an temporary cache of files and their contents. In my case, I had deleted a site with a .RDL and then recreated it with the same .RDL via code and it couldn't find it -- I was able to fix this by restarting Reporting Services via SharePoint Central Admin after I deleted the site, and before creating the new one. Seems like that's not really what you're seeing, but perhaps give stop/starting the service a try.